# transform dataset into case class via (wrapped) encoders

Tags: scala, dataframe, dataset, encoder

This is my dataset:

```
val bfDS = sessions.select("bf")
sessions.select("bf").printSchema


 |-- bf: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- s: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- a: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- b: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- c: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- a: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- a: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- b: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- c: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- d: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- a: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- b: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- c: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- tr: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- a: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- b: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- c: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- d: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- e: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- f: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- g: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cs: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- a: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- b: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- c: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- d: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- e: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- f: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- g: long (nullable = true)
```

1. I don't think I understand Scala datasets very well. A dataset is composed of rows, but when I print the schema, it shows an array. How does the dataset map to the array? Is each row is an element in the array?
2. I want to convert my dataset into a case class.

   case class Features( s: Iterable[CustomType], a: Iterable[CustomType], tr: Iterable[CustomType], cs: Iterable[CustomType])

How do I convert my dataset and how do I use encoders?

Answer (score 2):

First, [Spark `Row`s](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row) can encode a variety of values, including `Arrays` & `Structures`.

Second, your dataframe's rows are composed of only one column of type `Array[...]`.

Third, if you want to create a `Dataset` from your df, your `case class` must match your schema, in such case it should be something like:

```
case class Features(array: Array[Elements])
case class Elements(s: CustomType, a: CustomType, tr: CustomType, cs: CustomType)
```

Finally, an `Encoder` is used to transform your case classes and their values to the Spark internal representation. You shouldn't bother too much about them yet - you just need to `import spark.implicits._` and all the encoders you need will be there automatically.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
val ds: Dataset[Features] = df.as[Features]
```

---

Also, you should take a look to [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) as a reference.

Comment: Hello. why are you so mean? I stated that i did not understand the topic. I thank you anyway for the answer.